# Get month from date time now month, Get year from date time now year and write specific day

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Hello everyone i want search data from invoices and client by today date I'm using DateDiff() GETDATE() functions for example two tables

1 Client

```
 - ID   int
 - Name Varcher
```

2 Invoice

```
 - ID int
 - ClientID int
 - date  Datetime
 - Total  money
```

query

```
 Select * from client c 
 inner join invoice i on c.id = i.ClientID 
 WHERE DateDiff(dd, i.date, getdate()) = 0
```

when i run query the getdate() it is function to get date from date time now 
the date content current month and current year and current day
when i run query today the date is 08-23-2010, when i run query tomorrow the date is 08-24-2010.

Q - the query do something equal date i want get month from date time now month, get year 
from date time now year and write specific day only.

Comment: Sorry - I'm having difficulty understanding what you're asking for.  Could you provide an example of what you expect for output?

Comment: Very confusing question but I think you are trying to write a query that will filter invoices that are for the current month and year and you want the query to output just the day (since the month and year are assumed by the filter). Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @day integer

select @day = 10

Select * from client c 
inner join invoice i on c.id = i.ClientID 
WHERE 
DateDiff(dd, i.date, dateadd(dd,@day-datepart(dd,getdate()),getdate())) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your question clearly, but as far as I understand you want to have a time difference other than 0 days. You would then have to use other dateparts (first argument to `DateDiff()`) See the [MS documentation of DateDiff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794(v=SQL.90).aspx) for details, or the [DateAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819(v=SQL.90).aspx) function.

Furthermore, maybe you want to use

```
i.date between DateAdd(dd, -10, getDate) and getDate()
```

(which would show everything between ten days ago and today).